# jQuery request - answear undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm just starting with jQuery and have a problem. 
When i run this the answer that i'm getting is 
currency undefined
What do i do wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">      
        </script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://api.hotwire.com/v1/deal/hotel?apikey=xxx&limit=5&format=JSONP",
                    //url : "http://api.hotwire.com/v1/deal/hotel?apikey=xxx&limit=5&format=JSONP", 
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function(parsed_json) {
                        var currency = parsed_json['Result']['CurrencyCode'];
                        document.getElementById("currency").innerHTML = currency;
                        //alert("La temperatura actual en " + location + " es: " + temp_c);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Currency</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="currency"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `debugger` in your success callback to inspect the value of `parsed_json`. We cannot do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned object's `Result` property is an array, so use some index to reference its contents, e.g.:

```
success : function(parsed_json) { 
  var currency = parsed_json['Result'][0]['CurrencyCode']; 
  document.getElementById("currency").innerHTML = currency;
}
```